# Itens duplicados no Foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Tenho dois Inputs (`curso[]` e `formacao[]`) `html` e quando entre em loop com o `foreach` e começa a duplicar os itens que estão dentro do segundo `foreach`

***Esta é a minha classe***

```
class Pessoa {

private $Formacao;
private $Cursos;

function __construct($Formacao,$Cursos)
{

    $this->Formacao =  (array) $Formacao;
    $this->Cursos = (array) $Cursos;
}

public function setFormacao($Formacao){
    $this->Formacao = $Formacao;
}

public function getFormacao(){

    return $this->Formacao;
}

public function setCursos($Cursos){
    $this->Cursos = $Cursos;
}

public function getCursos(){
    return $this->Cursos;
}

public function getBody(){

    foreach ($this->getFormacao() as $formacao) {
            $body = "<ul><li>{$formacao}";
            foreach ($this->getCursos as $cursos) {
                $body.= "{$cursos}</li></ul>";
            }   
    }

    return $body;
}
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza mas acredito que vc não deveria ter os forechs encadeados, deveriam ser separados, pode confirmar isso?

Comment: Como é a relação? É de um curso para uma formação?

Comment: Não sei de onde vem essa informação, o mais confiável seria o curso ter o `id` da formação no banco de dados, assim vc sabe exatamente quais cursos estão em quais formações, só com o código da pergunta parece que eles são separados.

Comment: Não entendi a relação da Formação com os Cursos já que os dois são arrays independentes. Se for uma formação, com vários cursos, vindo esses dois arrays separados, como vc visualiza vincular corretamente os cursos às formações correspondentes?

Comment: Não deveria ser private $Formacao[]; private $Cursos[];? Senão não faz sentido o setFormacao uma vez que o construtor já faz isso!

Comment: Esses dados não são gerados em banco.

Comment: @William não precisa adicionar RESOLVIDO no titulo, o site funciona diferente de fóruns, e o recomendável é você postar como resposta abaixo a forma como resolveu o problema, e marcar como aceita, clicando no `v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acabei encontrando a solução. Ela foi muito simples usei o for ao invés do foreach, que é melhor para controlar iterações.